# import jQuery plugin in Js Files

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, ecmascript-6

I wanted to know how to import jQuery libraries after installing from npm.
I did the following, but I encountered the following error.

```
import countdown from 'jquery.countdown';
$.countdown = countdown;

$("#hours1").countdown("2020/05/01 16:00:00", function (event) {
    $(this).text(event.strftime('%H'));
});
```

and

```
import countdown from 'jquery.countdown';
window.$.countdown = countdown;

$("#hours1").countdown("2020/05/01 16:00:00", function (event) {
    $(this).text(event.strftime('%H'));
});
```

Error:

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).countdown is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

Try to import the scripts from the `node_modules` folder:

```
import 'jquery-countdown/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js';
```

Comment: Sorry, there is no path you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

i believe there is mistake on official NPM page.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-countdown

Try to install by NPM like this:

```
npm install --save jquery-countdown
```

and then use

```
import 'jquery-countdown/dist/jquery.countdown.min';
```